# Fork stays in compressed position while locked

Tags: suspension

So I recently replaced the stock suspension forks on my Giant Cypress Hybrid with a [Suntour CR9 Lock-out fork](http://www.bikewagon.com/sr-suntour-cr9-suspension-fork-700c-1-1-8-black-210mm-threaded?___store=default&utm_campaign=map&utm_medium=email&utm_source=yotpo&yotpo_token=375cd20593e373ffdeffa99c4630ee32dd7f99bc)
I noticed that (like my mountain bike with a Manitou fork), I can engage the lockout while the fork is partially compressed, but unlike the mountain bike’s Manitou fork, the Suntour does not return to the top position when un-loaded while locked. Instead it will remain in the position it was when I locked it.

My question is, would I be risking damage to the Suntour fork if I ride it while locked out in a partially compressed position? Or should I make sure to return it to its top position before locking?

(It may be relevant to note that the pre-load is adjusted with the same lock-out lever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many forks work that way.  I have a Pace fork that would lock in any position.  By locking in a compressed position, you get a bit better geometry for climbing (lowers the front end).  I doubt that you will hurt the fork riding in a locked/compressed/partially compressed position, but a quick check of you owners manual could probably confirm this.

Comment: Yeah, the owners manual is unfortunately shall I say; less than useful. i had done some googling & wasn't really able to find any mention either. 
I had asked in part thinking about the improvement in geometry for climbing & for cutting through the wind. I can lock it out low enough to drop the bars an inch & a half or so!
Thanks.